# Best match in search form auto-complete

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, rest

I have a search form which receives a list of possible search results from a rest api. If I enter: "Griffi", I get the following list returned via the api:

```
Griffin
Griffith
Griffiths
```

When the user then selects the form's "Search" button, I want "Griffin" to be sent to the submit.php script via the query string, instead of "Griffi". In other words, the first item in the list returned from the api. How do I achieve this?

Html5

```
<form class="search" action="https://myurl/submit.php" autocomplete="on">
    <label class="search__label">Enter:</label>
    <input type="search" class="search__input" name="stuff" required="">
    <button type="submit" class="search__button">Search</button>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
  $(".search__input").autocomplete({
    delay: 250,
    source: function(request, response) {
      var suggestURL = "https://myurl/index.php?startsWith=%QUERY";
      suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: suggestURL,
        success: function (data) {
           response(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the response data into a variable  like this:

```
success: function (data) {
       suggestionsAutocomplete = data //make this a global variable
       response(data);
}
```

And when sending a post request do the following:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  type: 'post',
  data: { search: suggestionsAutocomplete[0] },
  success: function( data ){
  }
});
```